# Iterate over python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a response (python dictonary) of Boto3 like this:

```
{
    'TagDescriptions': [{
        'ResourceArn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:11111111111:loadbalancer/app/AXXX001PRO/e5ca75b7',
        'Tags': [{
            'Key': 'STACK',
            'Value': 'ATENEA-ELB-TWRHL6'
        }, {
            'Key': 'APP_NAME',
            'Value': 'XXX001_ATENEA'
        }, {
            'Key': 'Environment',
            'Value': 'PRO'
        }, {
            'Key': 'NAT_PROFILE',
            'Value': 'LOW'
        }, {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'AXXX004PROBELB01'
        }]
    }],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'f5fba49b',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'f5fba49b',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'content-length': '1065',
            'date': 'Mon, 27 Mar 2023 16:15:01 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

Need iterate and get only the value of the key that string is equal to `APP_NAME`. But it's not valid to know the position because it can changes. I tested different ways but don't know to do it.

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your issue, then you should mark the one that best helped you as correct. This would help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there can be multiple tag descriptions and multiple tags, all you need to do is iterate over both of them in a nested for-loop:

```
data = {
    'TagDescriptions': [{
        'ResourceArn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:11111111111:loadbalancer/app/AXXX001PRO/e5ca75b7',
        'Tags': [{
            'Key': 'STACK',
            'Value': 'ATENEA-ELB-TWRHL6'
        }, {
            'Key': 'APP_NAME',
            'Value': 'XXX001_ATENEA'
        }, {
            'Key': 'Environment',
            'Value': 'PRO'
        }, {
            'Key': 'NAT_PROFILE',
            'Value': 'LOW'
        }, {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'AXXX004PROBELB01'
        }]
    }],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'f5fba49b',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'f5fba49b',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'content-length': '1065',
            'date': 'Mon, 27 Mar 2023 16:15:01 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}

app_name = None
for tag_desc in data['TagDescriptions']:
    for tag in tag_desc['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'APP_NAME':
            app_name = tag['Value']
            break

print(app_name)
```

In this example, I initialized the variable `app_name` to `None`, so if the tag does not exist, `app_name` will still be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested comprehension to iterate over all the `TagDescriptions` and all the `Tags` in those descriptions, then filter for the one(s) with the matching `Key`:

```
>>> res = {
...     'TagDescriptions': [{
...         'ResourceArn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:11111111111:loadbalancer/app/AXXX001PRO/e5ca75b7',
...         'Tags': [{
...             'Key': 'STACK',
...             'Value': 'ATENEA-ELB-TWRHL6'
...         }, {
...             'Key': 'APP_NAME',
...             'Value': 'XXX001_ATENEA'
...         }, {
...             'Key': 'Environment',
...             'Value': 'PRO'
...         }, {
...             'Key': 'NAT_PROFILE',
...             'Value': 'LOW'
...         }, {
...             'Key': 'Name',
...             'Value': 'AXXX004PROBELB01'
...         }]
...     }],
...     'ResponseMetadata': {
...         'RequestId': 'f5fba49b',
...         'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
...         'HTTPHeaders': {
...             'x-amzn-requestid': 'f5fba49b',
...             'content-type': 'text/xml',
...             'content-length': '1065',
...             'date': 'Mon, 27 Mar 2023 16:15:01 GMT'
...         },
...         'RetryAttempts': 0
...     }
... }
>>> [tag for desc in res['TagDescriptions'] for tag in desc['Tags'] if tag['Key'] == 'APP_NAME']
[{'Key': 'APP_NAME', 'Value': 'XXX001_ATENEA'}]
```